# Running Back-in-Time on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, backup, minecraft

So, I just installed Ubuntu Server and installed a basic, stripped-down graphical interface onto it so that I can use it. Since I'm new, I needed it. I am using it to run a Minecraft server, and was recommended the Back-in-Time package to use for backups. I installed the Back-in-Time package from the Ubuntu Software Center, but it didn't show up on the bar. I tried using the Dash, but it didn't show up either. How do I launch the application? I tried installing through terminal too, but that didn't work either. Please help!

Comment: Enter `software-center`

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer that you want to hear, but installing a graphical interface, even if its stripped down,  just to be able to use back-in-time , isn't a very linux server way of doing things.

Usually with a server you wish to use the minimal amount of packages. To keep the server secure un-bloated and easy to maintain / restore

I also question the need of a snapshot like backup. If you are running a mine craft server.
Do you require versions of your backups? Usually this would be something one would want for documents  / files / source code where versions matter. With a minecraft server. Wouldnt you just want the latest stuff so you can restore it?

Anyway, a non graphical versioning snapshot / backup software. would be rsnapshot.
you can find it [here( rsnapshot homepage)](http://rsnapshot.org/) .

Comment: [These are some more good reasons not to run a GUI on a production server.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI#Arguments_Against_a_GUI)

Comment: Really, this is not the answer.
No one asked about security, just on how to use Back in Time on Ubuntu Server.